# IOS - How to Insert data into different tables with relationship In Core Data Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, fetch, relationship

We have two tables with one to one relationship. `personel.idpersonel` maps to `personeltochart.idpersonel`.

1. personel
2. personeltochart

On login event, we sync data of `personel` table from a webservice, and save it into `personel` tables. We have to get other table data on another event and save it.

The question is when we try to fetch data from these two tables why we get data of `personel` table correctly but data from `personeltochart` table is nil?

### personel

firstname  
idpersonel

### personelToChart

id  
idpersonel

Here is an example of saving data of table:

```
                    let jsonEmza = try jsonDecoder.decode([JSONNameTabel].self, from: data)

                    var privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
                    privateContext = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext


                    jsonEmza.forEach({ (jsonCompany) in
                        let tabel = jsonCompany.tableName
                        if tabel == "Personel"{

                        jsonCompany.personel?.forEach({ (field) in
                                let personel = Personel(context: privateContext)
                                personel.firstname = field.firstName
                                personel.idpersonel = field.id

                            })
 do {

                            try privateContext.save()

                        } catch let saveErr {
                            print("Failed to save personel:", saveErr)
                        }

                        }
```

fetching example

```
    let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Personel>(entityName: "Personel")
   let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "idpersonel == %@", "147")
   fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    do {
        let listNameh = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        listNameh.forEach({ (item) in
            print(item.idpersonel ?? "")
            print(item.lastname ?? "")
            print(item.firstname ?? "")
            print(item.personelToChart?.id)

        })


    } catch let fetchErr {
        print("Failed to fetch Personel:", fetchErr)

    }
```

The data of `item.personelToChart?.id` is `nil`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: You have not set any relationship between the `Personel` created in the first code sample and the (presumably) `Chart` table. Just declaring the relationship isn't enough. You have to assign an object to the `personelToChart` property on `Personel`.

Answer (score 0):

It's like Sam said, you need assign an object to PersonelToChart on Personel. For example, here's my core data model

Leg (flightId, flightName, Aircraft)
Aircraft (aircraftId, aircraftName)
Make sure your relationship in Flight entity looks like[image: this]

```
let Aircraft = AircraftCoreData(context: self.persistentContainer.viewContext)
        secondAircraft.aircraftId = 02334
        secondAircraft.aircraftName = "ABC"

        leg.aircraft = Aircraft
```

You'll see that we created aircraft object, assigned values to its properties then assigned the object to leg.aircraft property. Now when you fetch the data, you won't get nil